# How to scan this line and use scan.skip()?

Tags: java, skip

I have a .txt file with lines of this format example : `torch ; 3.0 ; 23.0`

I want to scan it in order to place the first item in a String, and the second and third in a float.

Here is what I have done so far but the `scan.skip(" ; ")` doesn't work, I have also tried `scan.skip(Pattern.compile(" ; ")` but it didn't work either.

```
File file = new File(dir);
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        scan.skip(" ; ");
        scan.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(" ; "));
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String s = scan.next();
            float f1 = scan.nextFloat();
            float f2 = scan.nextFloat();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Do you have any solutions for me ?
Thanks

Comment: What *doesn't work* exactly mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `;` or `\n` as delimiter and no need to skip, also I'd suggest to use `Float.parseFloat(scan.next());`

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
scan.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[;\\n]"));
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String s = scan.next();
    float f1 = Float.parseFloat(scan.next());
    float f2 = Float.parseFloat(scan.next());
    System.out.println(s + " " + f1 + " " + f2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't change the delimiter of the `Scanner` you're using to read the `File`. Instead, instantiate an inner `Scanner` to parse the lines you read from the file. Aslo, I would use a [`try-with-Resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to make sure the `Scanner` (and `File`) are closed. Like,

```
File file = new File(dir);
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
        lineScan.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\\s*;\\s*"));

        String s = lineScan.next();
        float f1 = lineScan.nextFloat();
        float f2 = lineScan.nextFloat();
        System.out.printf("%s %.2f %.2f%n", s, f1, f2);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64186675/1553537) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64186677/1553537) would solve your problem.

However, I want to explain why *your code* does not work, and how can you make it work.

[Have a look](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#skip(java.util.regex.Pattern)) at `Scanner#skip(String pattern)` documentation, which says, that:

> If a match to the specified pattern is not found at the current position, then no input is skipped and a NoSuchElementException is thrown.

So, your `scan.skip(" ; ");` blocks the thread, and keeps reading the tokens, *until* your input matches the specified pattern (`;`) to skip, or a `NoSuchElementException` is thrown.

If you want to use `.skip(..)`, you can just change the order of your method calls, like:

```java
try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = scan.next();
        scan.skip(" ; ");
        float f1 = scan.nextFloat();
        scan.skip(" ; ");
        float f2 = scan.nextFloat();
    }
}
```

Comment: ohhh okk, thank you very much for taking the time to explain it